# Remove class on change of nested input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group red">
                <label for="q_11">11.   Met hoeveel personen woonde u het afgelopen jaar in uw woning?</label>
                <input name="q_11" value="" class="form-control" id="q_11" placeholder="Vul een getal in" required="" type="number">
              </div>
```

I would like to remove the "red" class from the div when the input field has changed but somehow I can't manage to get it working. I tried te following:

```
$('.red > input').on('change', function() {
      $(this).removeClass("red");
  });
```

I also have another case where the input field is nested in a "form-check" div

```
<div class="form-group red">
                <h6>7.  Hoeveel kWh hebben uw zonnepanelen het afgelopen jaar opgeleverd</h6>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" required="" name="q_7" id="q_7_1" value="1" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    Ik heb geen zonnepanelen bij mijn woning
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" name="q_7" id="q_7_2" value="2" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    <input class="form-control-sm form-control" name="q_7_number" id="q_7_number" type="number">
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" name="q_7" id="q_7_3" value="3" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    Ik heb zonnepanelen maar weet de opbrengst niet
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

For this one I tried:

```
$('.red.form-check > input').on('change', function() {
      $(this).removeClass("red");
  });
```

But again this is not working. I hope someone can help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$('.red > input').on('change', function() {
      $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the input, but you want to remove it from the parent. So use:

```
$(this).parent().removeClass("red");
```

Example:

```js
$('.red > input').on('change', function() {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("red");
  });
```

```css
.red {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group red">
                <label for="q_11">11.   Met hoeveel personen woonde u het afgelopen jaar in uw woning?</label>
                <input name="q_11" value="" class="form-control" id="q_11" placeholder="Vul een getal in" required="" type="number">
              </div>
```

Comment: Unforunately this also isn't working. No errors, even when trying to console.log() something it also doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't working? You can clearly see by the example in my answer that it works. Also, in your question's example where you have `$('.red.form-check')` there is no element with both of those classes. You need a space between them to select descendant elements. And in that case, you'd use `.closest('.form-group.red')` instead of `.parent()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `keyup` event.This will fire immediately when a key is released.

```
$('.red > input').keyup(function() {
   $(this).parent("div").removeClass("red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to target id's if we are talking of a single use, if not try using classes to make an easier listener.

You will have to use the `.parent()` functio to be able to access the parents class list.

When in doubt us `console.log` this way you would have seen that `this` was rthe input and no the parent

Also, if you are using jQuery take advantage of its syntaxis and make use of the next listener

```
.change( function() {});
```

```js
$('#q_11').change( function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("red");
  console.log("hi");
});
```

```css
.red { color:red;
background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group red">
  <label for="q_11">11.   Met hoeveel personen woonde u het afgelopen jaar in uw woning?</label>
  <input name="q_11" value="" class="form-control" id="q_11" placeholder="Vul een getal in" required="" type="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're targeting the input.  Try something like this:

```
$('.red > input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("red");
});
```

This will target the parent, instead of the element that you're testing for the change.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/webdevsoup/bemjzoap/6/

Answer (score 0):

selector is the problem  so i corrected it . ONCHANGE it rrermoves class "red" from element containing red

```js
$(".red >.form-check> input ,.red > .form-check > .form-check-label> input[type=number]").on("change",function(){
  $('.red').removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group red">
                <h6>7.  Hoeveel kWh hebben uw zonnepanelen het afgelopen jaar opgeleverd</h6>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" required="" name="q_7" id="q_7_1" value="1" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    Ik heb geen zonnepanelen bij mijn woning
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" name="q_7" id="q_7_2" value="2" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    <input class="form-control-sm form-control" name="q_7_number" id="q_7_number" type="number">
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" name="q_7" id="q_7_3" value="3" type="radio">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="q_7">
                    Ik heb zonnepanelen maar weet de opbrengst niet
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```